# Why is window.navigator.virtualKeyboard undefined in local network?

Tags: android, google-chrome, virtual-keyboard

When I try to access `window.navigator.virtualKeyboard` on my dev server in the local network, e.g. via 192.168.1.69 (dev server runs on desktop, accessing via mobile) it is always `undefined`. When deploying the app to the web it is available.

Testing with Chrome 105 on Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is because your testing environment isn't considered a secure context.

See https://w3c.github.io/editing/docs/virtualkeyboard/#hide-and-show-methods